# Complexes of coherent sheaves as complexes of vector bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety. It is often said that the derived category $D^b (X)$ is "just" something like complexes of vector bundles, however I haven't been able to find an elementary explanation of this.

I understand that a single coherent sheaf admits a *global* resolution by vector bundles (since $X$ is a variety and thus has the resolution property) which can be truncated to a resolution of finite length, since some kernel in the resolution is locally free (since $X$ is smooth).

However, an object in $D^b (X)$ is a bounded *complex* of coherent sheaves, e.g.
$$
\dotsb \to 0 \to \mathcal F_1 \to \mathcal F_2 \to \dotsb \to \mathcal F_{n-1} \to \mathcal F_n \to 0 \to \dotsb
\tag{$\ast$}
$$

Given a (finite) resolution $0 \to \mathcal E_{i,n_i} \to \dotsb \to \mathcal E_{i,1} \to \mathcal E_{i,0} \to \mathcal F_i \to 0$ of each $\mathcal F_i$ how can one write a bounded complex quasi-isomorphic to the complex $(\ast)$ in terms of the vector bundles $\mathcal E_{i,j}$?